# Python - Write file in intervals

Tags: python, file

I want to run a command using Python script, which writes a file in 10 seconds interval, then read it and analyze the content.

When I execute the script, the file is created but the content is not written.

```
cmd0 = 'airodump-ng -c '+ channel + ' --bssid ' + bssid + ' --write interval 10 -w psk wlan0mon'
cmd0 = cmd0.split()
p = Popen(cmd0,stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
time.sleep(10)#wait 10 seconds
for number in range(1, 101):
 path = 'psk-01.csv'
 print('read file')
 time.sleep(10)
p.terminate()
```

But if I execute the same command directly on the terminal, the file is written correctly.

```
airodump-ng -c 11 --bssid macx --write-interval 10 -w psk wlan0mon
```

What can I do?

Comment: Why is `stdin` `PIPE`? (perhaps the same question for `stdout` and `stderr`). I don't see any data being piped into stdin.

Comment: Do you want to take the output and do something with it? If not, you should use `subprocess.call`.

Comment: Because if I do not use it, in this case, airodump-ng launches its terminal interface and the script is stopped.

Comment: Did `p` terminate? What happens if you add `p.wait()` ?

Comment: _I want to launch a command from Python script, which writes a file in 10 seconds interval, then read it and analyze the content._ So yes, I want to take the output and do something with it.

Comment: And you dont' get a terminal interface on the command line?

Comment: Your `cmd0` has a `/psk`, but your command line variant does not? Typo?

Comment: You could try `p.stdin.close()` and `p.communicate()`.

Comment: @Gribouillis I use p.terminate (), as you can see in the posted recently updated code. @Evert When I run the command in the terminal directly I get the terminal interface, but I do not want it for my script. It is only `psk`, it is a typo.

Comment: You must not call `p.terminate()`. This is used to kill the subprocess. You want the subprocess to exit normally before you try to read the file. For this you can use `p.communicate("")` immediately after the call to `Popen()`. If this call hangs forever, it means that the subprocess never ends. Then you must understand why it does so. If `p.communicate("")` returns, then the subprocess finished its task. You can then check that `p.returncode` is 0, which means that the command exited without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I put next code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd0)

t =threading.Thread(target=myfunction,args=(values,))
t.start()
t.join()

p.terminate()
```

Instead of the next:

```
p = Popen(cmd0,stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
time.sleep(10)#wait 10 seconds
for number in range(1, 101):
 path = 'psk-01.csv'
 print('read file')
 time.sleep(10)
p.terminate()
```

And it works!